# loading of iis website too slow while debugging from visual studio 2008

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, iis

I'm debugging a asp.net website in visual studio 2008. When I visit the website through browser (at the usual http://localhost:56789), the pages load too slow. It looks almost as if there is a single socket/connection loading all the required pages/scripts etc sequentially.

If I publish the same website to a local folder and access it through the regular IIS (Windows 7/IIS 7.5), pages load really fast (as expected).

Is there a way to make the pages load faster during debugging. Is there any setting I need to modify in visual studio ?

Comment: Debugging is almost universally slower. Accept it, sorry.

Comment: @Chris: But isn't it supposed to at least load the static resources (*.js, *.css) faster ? Also this happens even with Ctrl+F5 (run without debugging option).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is the problem, but open your HOST file (`C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc`) in a text editor. Then add a `#` in front of `::1      localhost`. Save it and see if that speed it up.

Comment: @ivymike: Try uncommenting `127.0.0.1 localhost`. I found the thread I remembered this from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1416128/my-local-host-goes-so-slow-now-that-i-am-on-windows-7-and-asp-net-mvc

Comment: that worked like a charm! thanks a ton. It is even more faster when I go directly through http://127.0.0.1:56789/ :)

Answer (score 1):

I would debug through normal IIS if Cassini is slow.

Just go to tools->attach to process and attach to the IIS process.